# How to filter out events that contain a specific string while reading event viewer logs?

Tags: c#, .net, event-log, event-viewer

I am working on reading event viewer records in C# and I want to filter the events based on some substring I get in details,

For eg - I want to filter out events in Application log with eventid 1000 for some specific application name.

How can I can create a query checking for a particular string in details ?

```
string xpathQuery = "Event/System[EventID = 1000 and //Here need to add check for containing string in details]";

var eventLogQuery = new EventLogQuery(filter.ChannelName, PathType.LogName, xpathQuery);
var eventLogReader = new EventLogReader(eventLogQuery);

EventRecord eventRecord = eventLogReader.ReadEvent();
// Procced
```

Comment: You can't use a log query filter to perform wildcard text search against the rendered message (which may have been localized) - you can only search variable data fields in the message data, eg. `Event/[System[EventID = 1000] and EventData[Data = 'StringValueInQuestion']]`